# Cannot Install zerorpc through npm

Tags: node.js, installation, npm-install, zeromq

I am developing an electron-python app and I need to install `zerorpc` to share data between nodejs and python.

I first installed `zeromq` to the system

```sh
sudo apt install libzmq5
```

Then I installed it to python

```sh
pip install zerorpc
```

However, when I install `zerorpc` through `npm`

```
npm install zerorpc
```

It works fine until I get this error:

[image: List of Failure]

I have tried upgrading my `nodejs` version from `v15.0.0` to `v15.0.1`
I have also ran `ldconfig`, however, nothing seems to work.
Is there any way to go about this?

**PS:** I am using nodejs version `15.0.1` and npm version `7.0.3`

Comment: maybe it's incompatible with nodejs 15? `zerorpc` is outdated and last update was 2 years ago. Did you try it with nodejs 10, 12, or 14 versions?

Comment: Thanks, It works with nodejs `v12.0.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zerorpc` is outdated and last update was 2 years ago. I suppose it's incompatible with NodeJs 15. Try it with nodejs 10, 12, or 14 versions.